# AJAX Перезагружка страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

Мне ответили что этот код не может перезагружать страницу однако это не так если он перезагружает страницу у меня.
Как мне избавится от перезагрузки страницы

chat.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        <iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow'frameborder="no" height="935" width="935" src='iframe.php'>Chat</iframe>

    <br>    <input type='text' id="text" name='message'>
        <input type='button' id="button" value="send">
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready (function (
        ){  show();setInterval('show()',1000);  

            $("#button").bind("click", function (){
            var message = $("#text").val();
              $.ajax ({
                  url: "iframe.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {message},
                  dataType: "html"

              });  
            });  

            $("#button").bind("click", function (){
              $.ajax({
              url: "chat.html",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
              }
              });                    
            });


        });

             function show()  
            {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "chat.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

по нажатию на кнопку которая у меня одна там страница презагружается 
так же если выставить show(); setInterval('show()',1000); страница перезагружается, заметил такую вещь что если выставить интервал 10000 или 1 то страница будет перезагружатся с такой же частотой

iframe.php

```
<?php> session_start(); ?>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
//setTimeout("window.location.reload()",5000);
</script>
<body>

<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $sql = "insert into `messages` (`message`) values ('".$_SESSION['login']." :".$_POST['message']."')";
  mysql_query($sql);

}
$sql = "select message from `messages` last_insert_id";
$res = mysql_query($sql);


if($res)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
     printf("<div>%s</div>",$row->message);
    }
}
else
{ 
  echo "<p> <b>Error: ".mysql_error()."</b> </p>";
  exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы сами-то хоть что-нибудь из этого кода понимаете? Вы зачем-то создаете айфрейм с формой (?), которые потом затираете при успешном AJAX-запросе; вешаете два обработчика на один и тот же элемент; не используете `<form>` и `<button type="submit">`; используете устаревший метод [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/); используете `click` вместо `submit`. Приведенный вами код в действительности не может вызывать перезагрузку страницы (разве что клик по кнопке, но это не точно). Возьмите во внимание всё, что я написал, перепишите всё по уму и, возможно, проблема исчезнет сама собой.

Comment: @terron если я что то и не понимаю то это ajax

Comment: [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/Vpmx_1RCIOk)